# Heroku throws an error when retrieving JSON response with 40 elements

Tags: heroku

So I have an app deployed in Heroku, a Go backend with Angular 8 frontend using Hobby dinos. But today I noticed that one of my endpoints would not work if the result contains more than 40 elements. I tested this locally and this doesnt happen locally, so it must be a problem when running in Heroku. Any idea about what is going on here? Heroku throws the following error message:

> sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/invoices/g/range?from=2020-08-01T00:00:00.000+00:00&to=2020-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00" host=xxx-prod.herokuapp.com request_id=d113ba1c-f51a-4f57-8f02-31195da1b5f8 fwd="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=60ms status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what was going on here. It has to do with an unsolved Node issue, see: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12339

When using the POST handler I was receiving a large response that triggered that Issue. What I did is I rebuilt my logic in order to retrieve the response using a GET. Now it works as expected.